# How to test $save() of $resource in Angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a service that just returns $resource(). It is used in my controller to make a POST request using $save(). I am facing problem while writing Jasmine test for Controller > SettingAdd(). I am not able to set the correct mock for the service because of which my test fails. Below are my codes:

Note: Based on my analysis, the faked $save() method is not invoked correctly and hence the test fails

My Service:

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .factory('Setting', setting)
    .$inject = ['$resource', 'constants'];

function setting($resource, constants) {
    return $resource(constants.LOCAL_API_BASE_URL + '/api/settings', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true, ignoreLoadingBar: true }
    });
}
```

My Controller:

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .controller('SettingAddController', SettingAdd)
    .$inject = ['$q','Setting'];

function SettingAdd($q,Setting) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.setting = new Setting(); 
    vm.addSetting = addSetting;

    function addSetting() {

        vm.setting
            .$save()
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                vm.operationMsg.success = true;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                vm.operationMsg.success = false;
            })
        .finally(function () {
        });
    }
}
```

My Jasmine test:

```
describe("SettingAddController controller", function () {
    var scope,
        ctlr,
        SettingService;

    beforeEach(module('App'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, Setting) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        SettingService = Setting;

        var settingAddDeferred = $q.defer();

        spyOn(Setting.prototype, '$save').and.callFake(function () {
            return settingAddDeferred.promise;
        });


        ctlr = $controller('SettingAddController');

        settingAddDeferred.resolve({ msg: 'Success' });

        $rootScope.$apply();
    }));


    it("should make a POST request to setting API if form is valid when Save is clicked", function () {
        ctlr.addSetting();
        expect(ctlr.operationMsg.success).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, you don't expose the method addSetting() and this method it's not available in your test. first you should be :

```
vm.addSetting = addSetting;
```

In your spec, after the method, you should be use scope.$digest() (or $apply), don't before.

```
describe("SettingAddController controller", function () {
    var scope,
        ctlr,
        SettingService,
        settingAddDefer;

    beforeEach(module('App'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, Setting) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        SettingService = Setting;

        settingAddDeferred = $q.defer();

        spyOn(Setting.prototype, '$save').and.callFake(function () {
            return settingAddDeferred.promise;
        });


        ctlr = $controller('SettingAddController');

    }));


    it("should make a POST request to setting API if form is valid when Save is clicked", function () {
        ctlr.addSetting();
        settingAddDeferred.resolve({ msg: 'Success' });
        $rootScope.$apply();
        expect(ctlr.operationMsg.success).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I added that line. I hope I will find the solution for this issue soon.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Could you explain me the logic behind this

Comment: Sure. The before each it's executed before your spec. then your promise it's resolved before that the method that use the ngResource plugin it's executed. For fix this, in your spec:
ctlr.addSetting(); ---> create a promise that not have been resolved
| settingAddDeferred.resolve({ msg: 'Success' }); --> resolve the promise
| $rootScope.$apply(); ---> tells to angular that refresh the unresolved promises
| expect(ctlr.operationMsg.success).toBe(true); --> all it's in order. Your spec works